# Firebase ChildEventListener onChildChanged triggered twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to create To-Do android application. I'm use recyclerview and cardview to populate data fro firebase. But some weird things happen when i watch on Android Monitor and see my debug log fires twice `onChildChanged`:

```
D/DiaryAdapter: onChildChanged:-KIafq035E-pc6uT3Ej7
D/DiaryAdapter: onChildChanged:-KIafq035E-pc6uT3Ej7
```

and caused item on recyclerview blink twice (blink efect on item when it's updated)

i put this on MainFragment.java `onStart()`

```
        // Setup adapter
        diaryAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(),mDiaryRef);

        recyclerDiary.setAdapter(diaryAdapter);
```

On my adapter constructor

```
public DiaryAdapter(final Context context, DatabaseReference ref) {
 mContex = context;
 mDatabaseRefrence = ref;


 mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
   //Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

   Diary diary = dataSnapshot.getValue(Diary.class);
   mDiary.add(diary);
   mDiaryID.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
   notifyItemInserted(mDiary.size() - 1);

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
   Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

   Diary newDiary = dataSnapshot.getValue(Diary.class);

   int diaryIndex = mDiaryID.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());

   if (diaryIndex > -1) {
    mDiary.set(diaryIndex, newDiary);
    notifyItemChanged(diaryIndex);
   } else {
    Log.w(TAG, "onChildChanged:unknown_child:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

   int diaryIndex = mDiaryID.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());

   if (diaryIndex > -1) {
    mDiary.remove(diaryIndex);
    mDiaryID.remove(diaryIndex);

    notifyItemRemoved(diaryIndex);
   } else {
    Log.w(TAG, "onChildRemoved:unknown_child:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
   Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
   Toast.makeText(mContex, "Failed to load diary.",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 };

 ref.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
}
```

I'm following from firebase android sample [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database)

Edit: Database structure

```
{
  "diary" : {
    "2Y4XwraNoRdIFPBJY0XxwdPte0H2" : {
      "1437" : {
        "-KIahAPVU_WrmP5rDcAa" : {
          "created" : 1464159484316,
          "infaq" : {
            "selesai" : false
          },
          "ngaji" : {
            "ayatAkhir" : 0,
            "ayatMulai" : 0,
            "selesai" : true,
            "surahAkhir" : 0,
            "surahMulai" : 0
          },
          "puasa" : {
            "sahur" : false,
            "selesai" : true,
            "summary" : ""
          },
          "sholat" : {
            "ashar" : true,
            "dhuhur" : true,
            "done" : true,
            "mIsya" : true,
            "maghrib" : true,
            "subuh" : true
          },
          "summary" : "Puasa kedua Tos",
          "tanggal" : 2,
          "tarawih" : {
            "ringkasan" : "",
            "selesai" : true
          },
          "updated" : 1464186194796
         },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your database structure in firebase?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Post edited

Comment: Can you add code where you modify the database?

Comment: Now I'm test on my app and monitoring debug log, and there is no issue about that listener again, but i don't know why, maybe firebase server bugs and now has been fixed. Will update if issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep your data as flatten as possible according to the FireBase document.

Then, don't attach your listener to the root database for 2 reasons:

1. It will load the whole data set which affects your billing rates
2. It will be triggered once for every node in the json tree. So, in your case if you make a change in "ngaji" node, the listener will be triggered 5 times because "ngaji" is at the 5th level in the tree.

You can do the following:

```
ref.child("diary").child("2Y4XwraNoRdIFPBJY0XxwdPte0H2")
   .child("...").addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```